# Aframe register component typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, aframe

I have a simple component within Aframe listed below and [the typescript playground is hosted here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=46&ssc=5&pln=5&pc=1#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-LpME9HhKkiEEP3pck4DlOIAMtA0aH-GwAHdLQ8GwoFUaA4Cof5CkwSpsWrWtDUiOAt3fJCgKiWI-h7R8qD-D96O%20JjARY8DIOgpDYIvdstyCMBIkBPE73VXtn1fS8cycEAIEhW97xkl9iHkrNvy43tVOkljn0FOhhXhMUkRgV8aOAFBn3YjIsjRcsrM7WjAImT0IH4UxzAAEW9f5uOoT12DgABqJk4GMmBPRrAFgGiT1UXRKhMQiXFPQJOAACp-0A8SAQC5jqH7fo9Fc9iPK8pYYD8oqgqoTLwsi6LYsweLEuS3s0pxMDQty9iCqQere1K6BypzB1JuEu54K5RC9SwBwICovUHAw0iOgwI0oBwvDcMI%20BRk24dKK3b8930h8nzBCzTNFcU6BcztKsS6qfP8zpGiayL2K%20no%20nwga6OvGZaj3TKJpzV7PO84Q6v%20vq2LoxGxtw4HANBmo6lAkKobcz8qrh2rPtxgAvZHANRwH0byz8sfB8mJqmpRYKAA)

```js
interface GestureHandlerType {
  isVisible: boolean;
  initialScale: Vector3;
  scaleFactor: number;
  el: Entity<ObjectMap<Component<any, System<any>>>> & {
    sceneEl: any;
  };
  handleRotation: (event: CustomEvent<{ positionChange: { x: number; y: number } }>) => any;
  // handleScale: (event: CustomEvent) => any; // When i uncomment this line everything is broken
}

AFRAME.registerComponent<GestureHandlerType>('gesture-handler', {
        schema: {
            enabled: { default: true },
            rotationFactor: { default: 5 },
            minScale: { default: 0.3 },
            maxScale: { default: 8 }
        },

        init: function () {
            this.handleScale = this.handleScale.bind(this);  // This line throws error for not being defined 
            this.handleRotation = this.handleRotation.bind(this);
        },
        update: function () {
          // ... some other code here
        },

        remove: function () {
          // ... some other code here
        },

        handleRotation: function (event: CustomEvent) {
            if (this.isVisible) {
                this.el.object3D.rotation.y += event.detail.positionChange.x * this.data.rotationFactor;
                this.el.object3D.rotation.x += event.detail.positionChange.y * this.data.rotationFactor;
            }
        },

    // This method is throwing same error for not being defined
        handleScale: function (event: CustomEvent) {
                this.el.object3D.scale.x = this.scaleFactor * this.initialScale.x;
                this.el.object3D.scale.y = this.scaleFactor * this.initialScale.y;
                this.el.object3D.scale.z = this.scaleFactor * this.initialScale.z;
        }
    });
```

I have a problem where `this.handleScale` is not defined. When i try to define it in `GestureHandlerType` typescript throws an error that the whole component is not typed correctly. What would be the correct way of typing an Aframe component. I could not find it on the official docs [here](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html)

Comment: `handleScale` is mentioned no where in the sources or docs, so why do you believe this should be valid?

Comment: When i try to uncomment `handleScale: : (event: CustomEvent) => any` in GestureHandlerType it throws an error: `'{ schema: { enabled: { default: boolean; }; rotationFactor: { default: number; }; minScale: { default: number; }; maxScale: { default: number; }; }; init: () => void; update: () => void; remove: () => void; handleRotation: (event: CustomEvent<...>) => void; handleScale: (event: CustomEvent<...>) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentDefinition<GestureHandlerType>'`

Comment: You should uncomment the `handleScale` definition in the interface for sure.  Your `GestureHandlerType` is a custom type, and defines properties such as `isVisible` which you are NOT defining in the object passed to `registerComponent`.  They either need to be initialised (included in the object) or made optional (and the code amended to deal with undefined).

Comment: NB: 'everything is broken' isn't correct.  The whole object is marked as an error because the whole object fails to meet the interface requirement, and the error messages states which properties are missing.

Comment: Well I get that but what would be the proper way of defining a type for both `handleRotation` and `handleScale`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with those definitions. It’s the other properties that are missing that’s causing the problem.